# Different object library in utilities of xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, object, xcode5, utilities

I have observed two different scenarios in **Object Library** present in **Utilities** pane of Xcode 5. Below are screenshot for the same.

[image: First Object Library]     [image: Second Object Library]

The Second Object Library appears apparently in utilities. When to use the Second Object Library? Also, when does this library appears?

Comment: below one is for desktop application development

Answer (score 0):

It happend to me lot of times and I think it's just a visual bug. It should be caused by the fact that Xcode is still loading all the elements of the scene. Anyways if it persists you should try this:  in the Build Settings, change the "iOS Deployment Target" pulldown to a different SDK, then change it back. After that, you should get iOS objects back.

Comment: This appears mostly when project is opened first time. In order to hide this select XIB files.